# why my css flexbox isn't affecting my div even though it worked on other section

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a text `div` and picture `div` next to each other using flexbox and, even though I did the same thing before and it worked perfectly, this time for some reason it's not working.

This my HTML and CSS code:

```css
.hero-introduction {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

.hero-images {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-introduction">
    <h2>Elena Joy <br> Photography</h2>
    <p>paragraphe here</p>
    <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-images">
    <img class="hero-elena" src="images/elena-joy.png" alt="picture of elena joy">
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `display:flex` to .hero class and `flex-direction:row`

```css
.hero{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   }
.hero-introduction {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 40rem;
}
.hero-images {
    flex: 1 1 40rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
            <div class="hero-introduction">
                <h2>Elena Joy <br> Photography</h2>
            <p>paragraphe here</p>
            <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hero-images">
                <img class="hero-elena"  
                src="images/elena-joy.png" 
                alt="picture of elena joy">
            </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i know it's a simple question but i got confused it was not working